# Easy ways to get sql query results emailed in the form of attachment

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to run small query ( eg: `select * from` ) and have its results emailed to me (in the form of attachment) when I run that. What is the easiest way?

This is a report I need to generate on a monthly basis

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the below Code as per your requirement. You need to have SMTP configured on your server and execute permission.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'nationstar University',
@recipients = 'donald@nation.com',
@query = 'select FNAME,LNAME from PED.dbo.TD_EmployeeProfile_FinalV2 where manager_number=100000491' ,
@subject = 'Test email',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename='filename.xls',
@query_result_separator='   ' -- tab
```

Comment: hi..when i execute the above sp, will the  email be sent only to the emails provided in the profile ?
 And, is this sp already present or do i have to create one?
For now, I have setup database email and created a profile

Comment: Yes it will send emails to only email id listed in the @rec and that is system SP it should be there already .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Database Mail but it differs slightly depending on your version of `SQL Server`.

You first have to make sure that you have an SMTP server that you can use and access rights to relay email through a sender email address.

You can find a detailed tutorial that can be setup through `SQL Server Management Studio` here: https://www.codeproject.com/tips/846204/how-to-send-mail-using-sql-server-part

Comment: Thank you. I am new to sql. So, wanted few clarifications.
1.  While configuring database email, it asks for profile name and account name. Whats the difference ?

2. Should I give the query (whose results I want as an attachment)
in the @query option? ( the query that has been given above)

3. Once this setup is done, where should I run the job to get the query results as an attachment?

Comment: 1. Profile is a parent entity that can have many Accounts under it. If one accounts fails, then the next Account is selected in the same Profile. Just Enter the same names that you see in the example you'll be good to go. 2. Exactly. 3. Follow Step 12 in my link

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you have an SSRS server running on that sql instance, you could set up a monthly subscription with a simple report containing your query results.

Answer (score 0):

Database Mail is probably the easiest solution, and you already have a couple of good answers on how to do that.

If that's not an option for one reason or another, as long as you have an SMTP server available, you could create a simple SSIS package with a Data Flow Task to run the query to a file and a Send Mail Task to send the file to you. The package can be scheduled as a SQL Agent Job.